# "Basis" Version of a Local Connectedness Theorem

Tags: general-topology

> A space $X$ is locally connected if and only if for every open set $U$ of $X$, each component of $U$ is open in $X$.

The above is a theorem in Munkres' Topology book (theorem 25.3). As usual, I always wonder whether a given theorem is true when open sets are replaced with basis elements. I just proved that $X$ is locally connected if and only if $X$ has a basis entirely comprised of connected sets, thinking that this might help. But I cannot quite connect the pieces. So my question is

> Does a "basis" version of the above theorem hold?

Comment: What would this basis version look like actually? Do you mean that for a topological space $X$ with basis $\mathcal{B}$, we have that $X$ is locally connected if and only if for every basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}$, each component of $B$ is open in $X$?

Comment: @Demophilus Exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: The property is already defined by a base property: $X$ is locally connected iff every point has a local base of connected neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't imagine the proof to be that different from the original version: Let $X$ be a topological space with basis $\mathcal{B}$. Suppose for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ we have that each component of $B$ is open in $X$. Now take any $x \in X$ and any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. By definition there is a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset U$. Now let $C$ be the component of $B$ containing $x$. Then $x \in C \subset U$ and $C$ is open and connected. So $X$ is locally connected.

To prove the converse assume $X$ is locally connected. By the above theorem, we have that every open $U \subset X$, each component of $U$ is open. Since every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is open, each component of $B \in \mathcal{B}$ must be open too.

Comment: For the proof in your first paragraph, aren't we suppose consider a component of $U$ and conclude it is open in $X$?

Comment: Why? If you want to prove that $X$ is locally connected at $x$, it is sufficient to prove that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there exists another open connect neighbourhood $V$ that is contained in $U$.

Comment: Ah! Of course. I was trying to exclusively use theorem 25.3 when I attempted proving my conjecture, and forgot that I could resort the definition: sometimes it's good to go back to the roots of it all.